# hide div if container div has less charecter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing this to develop a read more. How do I hide the read more if the  `#pdpTab4`  has less than `540` charecters to begin with.

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var myDiv = $('#pdpTab4');
        myDiv.html(myDiv.html().substring(0,540));
        $('#pdpTab4').append('<div id="readOne">Read More></div>');
</script>
```

Comment: you forgot closing bracets of docuemnt ready `});`

Comment: I think it would be better to do this server side instead of javascript.

Comment: You should use your myDiv variable instead of re-executing the jQuery selection $('#pdpTab4'), performance wise.

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea. If your div contains any actual HTML, you're going to risk cutting off closing tags or parts of attributes, etc. For example your code might produce a string ending with `'and that's why I like <a href="http://google.c'`

Comment: @meagar: which is, incidentally, why I deleted my own answer. It seemed to be begging for trouble, though it worked within the constraints of the question (just bad, *bad* side-effects).

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
if ($('#pdpTab4').html().toString().length > 540) {
$('#pdpTab4').append('<div id="readOne">Read More></div>');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit different but nice approach:

```
$('#readOne').toggle($('#pdpTab4').text().length > 540);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/uF4BB/